# Magento 2.1.5 CORS problem

Tags: magento2, nginx, magento2.1.5

On my localhost i create a react app (getting data from magento 2 rest api). 
Magento is set on vagrant so they are on other domains.

When I try to send request ...

```
   var uploadReq = new Request(LOGIN_URL, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        })

    });

    fetch(uploadReq)
        .then(this._requestHandler)
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
        });
```

.. I get an CORS error:

```
 Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I found this config example: https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

But nothing has changed.

Comment: It's no Magento or NGINX issue, it's an issue related to JavaScript and HTTP Security protocol. I had this problem.

Comment: How did you solve this issue ?

Comment: Uploading my files to server with https and domain.